Does adding a title to a separate property render that a community property?
For community property states (e.g. California), does adding a title of a spouse render a separate property a community property? Why or why not? Thanks.

Adding another person to the title (spouse or not) doesn't necessarily make it community property in California.
"Community property" is defined in the California Family Code Sec. 760:


Except as otherwise provided by statute, all property, real or personal, wherever situated, acquired by a married person during the marriage while domiciled in this state is community property.


So depending on the details of the transaction the spouse's part may or may not be community property.
However, a married person can donate separate property to the community. The exact form of title vesting matters. Here's the different forms to hold title in California, and some forms would render a previously separate property to become community property - if the title explicitly says so.
